# why this not adding to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a multidimenssional array like this

```
var myArray = new Array();
          var test = new Array(1, 100,200,2);
        $.each(test, function(index, val) {

            myArray['value'].push(val);
            myArray['index'].push(index);
        });
```

but console.log(myArray) shows me no values;

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object literal instead of an array:

```
var myHash= {
    value: [],
    index: []
},
test = [1, 100,200,2];

$.each(test, function(index, val) {
    myHash['value'].push(val);
    myHash['index'].push(index);
});
```

[You shouldn't use arrays as associative arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). Arrays are accessed by 0-based index and you shouldn't assign arbitrary properties to arrays.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/F7Zx5/

Comment: this doesn't create a multidimentional array

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is misusing the term "Multidimensional Array"

Comment: can I use object instead of an array for this

Comment: and if I can then how? since that article makes sense of not using associative arrays in js

Comment: Yes... My answer outlines how to accomplish that.